# How to add www-authenticate header to HttpListenerResponse in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, header, system.net, www-authenticate

I have a custom Web Stack with custom self-hosted server (no IIS, no WCF). It uses *HttpListener* to get *HttpListenerContext* that is processed by pipeline of modules. So, I am working with *HttpListenerRequest* and *HttpListenerRespose* in processing modules.

Now I need to return *401 Unauthorized* to the client in some specific cases. Response should also include *WWW-Authenticate* header with specific challenge. So, I can just set *StatusCode* of the *HttpListenerRespose* = 401 and it works fine. But when I try to add *Www-Authenticate* header to the resonse - I get an exception: "The 'WWW-Authenticate' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name".

As I can see, WWW-Authenticate header is protected for response. [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse.headers) says that I can't "set a Content-Length, Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding, or WWW-Authenticate header using the Headers property". There are KeepAlive and ContentLenght64 properties for two of them but "You cannot set the Transfer-Encoding or WWW-Authenticate headers manually"

So, what is a possible solution? How should I return 401 response with specific WWW-Authenticate header correctly?

Comment: Set it on the listener - HttpListener.AuthenticationSchemes (you want Basic)

Comment: Thank you, Alex. It seems to be what I need. So, what if I want to specify something like 'Token realm='myrealm', error='token_expired'' in the header?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290559/httplistener-with-jwt-and-basic-auth-how-to-send-www-authenticate-self-hosted topic, it seems that System.Net.HttpListener supports only bulit-in auth schemas. And its not possible to configure it to work with JWT (in my case). Sad.

Answer (score 0):

HttpListenerResponse.AddHeader bypasses this restriction. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListenerResponse.cs,265